# How to fix LazyColumn Composable scrolling problem

Tags: android, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm trying to embed a horizontally scrollable table within a Composable. However whenever I engage horizontalScrolling the container goes 'blank', as shown. Also figured out that the container or LazyColumn itself has to have a .size to constrain the viewable width, is this normal?

Is it something to do with the column weights? As shown the column is either incorrectly squashed or haywire.

```
  LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .size(400.dp)
                //  this makes things go blank
```

.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())

```
        ) {
            item {
                Row(
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
                ) {
                    TableCell(
                        text = "Invoice",
                        weight = column1Weight,
                        alignment = TextAlign.Center,
                        title = true
                    )
                    TableCell(text = "Date", weight = column2Weight, title = true)
                    TableCell(text = "Status", weight = column3Weight, title = true)
                    TableCell(text = "Status", weight = column4Weight, title = true)
                    TableCell(text = "Status", weight = column5Weight, title = true)
                    TableCell(text = "Status", weight = column6Weight, title = true)


                }
                Divider(
                    color = Color.LightGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(1.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }


            itemsIndexed(invoiceList) { _, invoice ->
                Row(
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {
                    TableCell(
                        text = invoice.invoice,
                        weight = column1Weight,
                        alignment = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                    TableCell(text = invoice.date, weight = column2Weight, alignment = TextAlign.Center)
                    TableCell(text = invoice.status, weight = column3Weight)
                    TableCell(
                        text = invoice.amount,
                        weight = column4Weight,
                        alignment = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                    TableCell(text = invoice.filler, weight = column5Weight)
                    TableCell(text = invoice.killer, weight = column6Weight)
                }
                Divider(
                    color = Color.LightGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(1.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }


        }
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .size(20.dp))

    // second table
}
@Composable
fun RowScope.TableCell(
    text: String,
    weight: Float,
    alignment: TextAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    title: Boolean = false
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        Modifier
            .weight(weight)
            .padding(10.dp)

        ,
        fontWeight = if (title) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal,
        textAlign = alignment,
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

[image: squashed]
[image: blank]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not know what values are behind your columnWeight variables I think the weights are the issue. You have defined a horizontal scrollable LazyColumn, which means its width is undefined. But you also defined a weight for your TableCells which means each TableCell takes x% space of the max width.

But as the width of the Lazycolumn is undefined the application does not know how big the Tablecells should be (x% of undefined = ?)

Try to replace the weights with a fixed width for your cells. And you do not need to set a size for your LazyColumn.

Here a small basic example:

```
@Composable
fun TestView() {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .background(Color.DarkGray)
    ) {
        items(count = 10) {
            Row {
                repeat(10) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .size(50.dp)
                            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```